# android - EditText height resize based on keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext

I am having an activity in android where there is an editbox and 3 buttons below the editbox. Please see attachment. When this activity is launched, the default state is STATE1.(Please see image). The keyboard is visible by default. Now when I press the back button or dispose the keyboard, I wish to have the edittext resized and occupy the whole screen as shown in STATE2.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I have the height of the edittext hardcoded to some dp based on the target device. I believe this has to be changed. Can anyone help me in how to accomplish this.

The XML of the layout file is below as well as the screencap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"            
        android:background="@drawable/newback"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textFilter|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
       />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/PostMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/newbutton_corner"
            android:text="@string/SubmitMessage"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CancelMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/newbutton_corner"
            android:text="@string/CancelMessage"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/DeleteMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/newbutton_corner"
            android:text="@string/DeleteMessage"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `EditText` as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textFilter|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />
```

Add `layout_weight = 1`

In my opinion you **do not** need `adjustPan`. I will leave it upon you to decide. The behaviour will be different and you can try it out. Here is what the documentation says about `adjustPan`:

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Your buttons at the bottom may get hidden if using this. **Instead use `adjustResize`:
Put this line in the activity inside `AndroidManifest`**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used your code. I am not able to view the three buttons. the keyboard hides the button. In state 1 , the button was displayed. Any pointers??

Comment: you need to do add this in the activity (inside `AndroidManifest.xml`): `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` See updated answer

Comment: Perfect 10 for your help Amulya Khare. Thanks a lot. Very much pleased

Answer (score 6):

Try this.. in your manifest.

```
<activity
      android:name="Activity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

and your edittext use `<requestFocus />` for from that start itself it'll focus

and `android:layout_weight="1"` it will automatically fill the screen.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"            
        android:background="#696969"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textFilter|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
       >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, its simple.

1. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ,, add this attribute to you manifiest under required activity
2. Set width and height of your text view to match_parent

Done.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and change `android:layout_height="150dp"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`